# Regression Model - suicide rates

Tags: multiple-regression

[image: My plots look like the figure I attached, please suggest, what should I do next? My dataset has Prestige, income, education, and suicide rates for 36 occupations. The suicide rate is the response variable. Do I need any transformation here in response? I tried log transformation in the response variable, then also normal QQ plot not looking good. Please suggest.]

My plots look like the figure I attached, please suggest, what should I do next? My dataset has Prestige, income, education, and suicide rates for 36 occupations. The suicide rate is the response variable. Do I need any transformation here in response?  I tried log transformation in the response variable, then also normal QQ plot not looking good. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to model the error term by regressing e^2 on your Xs. Then use it's fitted values in a Weighted Least Squares regression where you model the weights (like 1/(error.fitted^2) for example).
However, it seems that you are working with a ratio as your Y variable, so if you have the data to decompose that ratio into two count variables you could instead try a Poisson Regression with offset.

Comment: I want to use only multiple linear regression, not poisson. We are not considering it as ratio data for now.